# How to convert or separate text file into column format records like excel or csv

Tags: batch-file

Thanks in advance..
I have one text file which contains SQL records separated by pipe'|'.
I want each record in separate column.
For example the text file contains above data :-

```
Name|address|status
John|USA|A1, active
Bob|UK|A3, active
Merry|NYC|A2, active
```

I want to convert it to excel using batch script. I don't want to use CSV file, because sometimes record (column) contains value which is separated by commas.

Comment: Instead of batch converting: choose field separator(s) in the Excel _import_ dialog there...

Comment: Read [Import or export text (.txt or .csv) files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba) and use [Text Import Wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Text-Import-Wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857) of Excel.

Comment: Thanks Mofi it is useful for me.

Comment: did you know, you can tell excel which char to use as separator in csv? Put `sep=|` as the first line of your csv and open it with Excel. This line will not  be part of your spreadsheet, it only tells Excel to use `|` as field separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would approach that in powershell. Take the data, split on the pipe, wrap the column in quotes, join it as csv then save it to a file. By putting quotes around the data, excel will read the csv correctly even if you have comas in the data.

```
# $data = @("Name|address|status","John|USA|A1, active","Bob|UK|A3, active","Merry|NYC|A2, active")
$data = Get-Content data.txt

$results = @()
foreach($line in $data)
{
    # Split on pipe
    $columns = $line -split '\|'

    # Wrap each column in quotes
    $columns = $columns | %{'"{0}"' -f $_}

    # Rejoin the line
    $results += $columns -join ','
}

# Save to a file
$results | Set-Content test2.csv
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.. Kevmar I can't put double quotes and commas manually I have thousands of line please suggest another code.

Comment: That first line is test data and is commented out. The second line will read your file. The code puts in the double quotes and commas where needed. Nothing manual about it.